# Custom Post Type Loop Doesn't Load All Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I'm trying to load my custom posts using a php loop and it only loads 5 posts. I'm using CPT UI Wordpress plugin code to register a post:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_homepage_brands() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Homepage Brands.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Homepage Brands", "astra" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Homepage Brands", "astra" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Homepage Brands", "astra" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "homepage_brands", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "homepage_brands", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_homepage_brands' );
```

and I use this code to create a loop and to load images from posts a loop:

```
<div class="your-class">
<?php
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'homepage_brands',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
                'order'     => 'ASC',
);

$brand = get_posts($args);
foreach ($brand as $post) {
                setup_postdata($post);
                $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full');
                if (!$thumbnail)
                                continue;
?>

<div><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>"></div>

                <?php
}

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```

And yes, I checked Wordpress posts setting, and amount of posts is set to hundreds. Also, weirdly, I use the same exact way to loop another custom post and it works.

I think something is off with the way I register that post type, but I'm not sure.
I just tried the same way/code on a different server and it all works perfectly.

Comment: Take a look at a similar question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159419/wp-query-on-custom-post-type-not-displaying-multiple-loops-get-template-part)

Comment: Doesn't seem like my issue. I get few posts displayed, but it's not 20 as it should be, it's just 5.

Comment: Are you sure all your posts have featured image set?

Comment: I solved the issue. It was a faulty plugin "Post Migrate" breaking custom posts. I removed it, created a new post type and it all worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a faulty "Post Migrate" wordpress plugin. Removing it and creating a new post type fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_homepage_brands() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Homepage Brands.
     */

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Homepage Brands', 'astra' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Homepage Brands', 'astra' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( 'Homepage Brands', 'astra' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Homepage Brands', 'astra' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Brands', 'astra' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Brands', 'astra' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Brands', 'astra' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Brands', 'astra' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Brands', 'astra' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Brands', 'astra' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Brands', 'astra' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Brands:', 'astra' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No Brands found.', 'astra' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No Brands found in Trash.', 'astra' ),
        'featured_image'        => _x( 'Brands Image', 'astra' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set Brands image', 'astra' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove Brands image', 'astra' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as Brands image', 'astra' ),
        'archives'              => _x( 'Project archives', 'astra' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into Brands', 'astra' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this Brands', 'astra' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter Brands list', 'astra' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Brands list navigation', 'astra' ),
        'items_list'            => _x( 'Brands list', 'astra' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "homepage_brands", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "homepage_brands", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_homepage_brands' );

<div class="your-class">
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'homepage_brands',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);

$brand = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $brand->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $brand->have_posts() ) {
        $brand->the_post();

        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');
        if (!$thumbnail)
            continue;
    ?>
    <div><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>"></div>
    <?php
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```